# How to create custom animation between child UIViewControllers in container UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have my custom `UIViewController` that behaves as a container. I have created some child view controllers that are swapped but I would like to add some custom animation when they are replaced.

For example, 2 view controllers have similar UI - one has 2 buttons and the other has only 1. I would like to animate *morphing* that old view controller's left button is shrinking and the right one is growing to the left if that description has any sense.

Is this possible using this API from `UIViewController`? Is this a valid API at all or some obscure, old-school way?

```
func transition(from fromViewController: UIViewController, 
             to toViewController: UIViewController, 
       duration: TimeInterval, 
        options: UIView.AnimationOptions = [], 
     animations: (() -> Void)?, 
     completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)
```

Any ideas and samples would be highly appreciated. I cannot find much (in Swift) for custom animations between `UIViewController` in containment based on another `UIViewController`

Comment: All the parent view controller does is own both of its child's views. And the child's views are just that, plain `UIView` objects. So just treat the transition between the two children like you would animate between two views. Don't even think about view controllers right now, just a couple of views that need to change places. When a child wants to change places (perhaps through a button tap), call a function in the parent that animates the open view to a hidden state and the closed view to a visible state. It's as straightforward as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

For the animation effect you are expecting, you don't have to animate the transition. Just animate the buttons' size changes on the first view controller itself and once you achieve the final state (where the first vc looks like the second vc), replace the first vc with second vc with **no** animation. It'll be quick enough to appear as if it was the transition between the vc's that got animated.